# How can I restore the database when mesh is not starting up any more?

Tags: gentics-mesh

Due to low memory our mesh instance crashed and left the database in an inconsistent state. Mesh is not starting up anymore and I have no chance to use the restore end points. Is there an alternative way to restore the database?

Here is the error output:

```
SEVERE: $ANSI{green {db=storage}} Exception during index 'e.has_branch_inout' deletion
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OPageIsBrokenException: Following files and pages are detected to be broken ['e.has_field_container_branch_type_lang.hib' :86;], storage is switched to 'read only' mode. Any modification operations are prohibited. To restore database and make it fully operational you may export and import database to and from JSON.
DB name="storage"
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.checkLowDiskSpaceRequestsAndReadOnlyConditions(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:5143)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.deleteIndexEngine(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:2113)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexAbstract.create(OIndexAbstract.java:259)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexMultiValues.create(OIndexMultiValues.java:258)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexMultiValues.create(OIndexMultiValues.java:44)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexManagerShared$RecreateIndexesTask.createAutomaticIndex(OIndexManagerShared.java:600)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexManagerShared$RecreateIndexesTask.recreateIndex(OIndexManagerShared.java:586)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexManagerShared$RecreateIndexesTask.recreateIndexes(OIndexManagerShared.java:534)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexManagerShared$RecreateIndexesTask.run(OIndexManagerShared.java:515)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: I have not yet seen this issue before - If you want you could provide me with the DB and I can take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

We managed to recover the database by using the OrientDB shell.

- First we deleted all the *.hib files
- Started the OrientDB shell via docker
- Then we exported the old data
- Created a new database
- Finally we imported the old data to the new database and started mesh

Answer (score 0):

You could try to delete all the *.hib files in your storage directory and start Mesh again. (Create a backup up-front)

Otherwise you would unfortunately need to download OrientDB 2.2.x, add the mesh db in the OrientDB installation and invoke the import/export:

https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Export-Format.html

If the REST API of Gentics Mesh is reachable you could also try to invoke the backup and restore endpoint. This could be done via the *mesh-cli*:

```
mesh admin backup
mesh admin restore
```